# CSS for Radio Button, Label and Optional Caption in Predefined HTML Structure

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I am trying to style some form elements in a specific way, but I don't have control over the HTML structure and Javascript is not an option. I need a CSS-only solution, if one exists.

The end result I want to achieve would be something like this:

```
O This is the radio button label if
  it needs to wrap to the next line.
  [There is an optional caption.]

O This is another radio button label.
  [There is a caption here]

O Radio Button
O Radio Button
O Radio Button
```

The HTML in question is X series of radio buttons and their labels. The labels have an optional caption (a `<span>` tag) inside the `<label>` tag.

The `<label>` needs to only extend as wide as what it contains, so I've been using `display:inline` for that. That works fine, but if it stretches onto multiple lines, it wraps underneath the radio button, which is what I'd like to avoid.

```
O This is the radio button label if
it needs to wrap to the next line.   <-- Wraps under radio button
  [There is an optional caption.]

O This is another radio button label.
  [There is a caption here]

O Radio Button
O Radio Button
O Radio Button
```

If I add `float:left` and `margin-bottom:1em` to the radio button, then it kind of works. The `margin-bottom` causes the second line to be wrapped correctly, but only for as many lines as the height of the radio button plus the margin. A third line won't wrap, for instance.

In addition, it either blows out the single-line radio buttons:

```
O Radio Button
  Radio Button
O Radio Button

O
```

Or doesn't do enough and the floats stack:

```
O Radio Button
  O Radio Button
    O Radio Button
```

Floating both the `<input>` and the `<label>` causes wrapping issues on the multiline because now the label stretches to 100%:

```
O
This is the radio button label if
it needs to wrap to the next line.
[There is an optional caption.]

O This is another radio button label.
  [There is a caption here]
```

I've created a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qdyr7g83/ that shows where I currently am.

If I had control over the HTML, I'd chuck the input and label into separate divs and control layout that way, but I'm kind of stuck with what I have. Does anyone have any thoughts about this? Am I going to have to live with the label wrapping?

Comment: Please include a sample of the HTML in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `calc` (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), given the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Some random text</p>
    <input type="radio" id="rdo1" /><label for="rdo1">Some Text Lets make this really long, so long that it wants to wrap to another line. See It is really really long <span>This is a caption. It is also really long and should wrap over atleast one line.</span></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rdo2" /><label for="rdo1">Some Text <span>Some Other Text</span></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rdo3" /><label for="rdo1">Some Text <span>Some Other Text</span></label>
    <input type="radio" id="rdo4" /><label for="rdo1">Some Text <span>Some Other Text</span></label>    
</div>
```

You could use the following CSS:

```
.container input[type="radio"]
{
    display:block;
    width:15px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

.container label 
{
    display:block;
    width:calc(100% - 30px);
    float:left;
}

.container label>span
{
    display:block;
    margin:5px 0;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbqg7k1w/2/